# What option(s) would you use to sort a file named foo in place, that is replacing the original file with the sorted version?

Tags: sort

I have this homework question. I looked at the man page for sort and I believe the answer is `-o, --output=FILE` Is that correct?

It is a Fedora server.

We're supposed to look on man pages, if there is no man page related to the subject than use an info page. If no info page exists either than use the internet.

Comment: I've edited out your additional questions. It's bad practice on Stack Exchange to combine questions like this.

Comment: Sorry. Is there any way to delete the question? So that I can redo it.

Comment: No, you don't have to delete it. I edited it for you (it'll be approved by the community soon) but in the future you can edit your question right under the tags. And welcome to Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a file named foo in place - sort of:

```
set TMP=$(mktemp)
sort foo > $TMP
mv $TMP foo
```

This redirects the output of `sort` into a temporary file, which then replaces foo.

Comment: This will result in an empty `foo`. The shell will open `foo` for writing and truncate it before `sort` even starts

Comment: This works, but I wouldn't exactly call writing the whole thing out to a new file "in-place" :). On the other hand, it's the same thing `-o` does, and that's clearly what the teacher expected

Comment: @user2227702 you don't have to thank people - instead, upvote! (You can't do this yet but it's only 5 rep)